# How do I create a text file with Windows-1251 encoding in Lua?

Tags: windows, lua, character-encoding

I use `io.open(somepath,"w")`, it creates txt file in UTF-8 encoding, how do I change it to Windows-1251?

Comment: Lua is agnostic about what bytes you write to the file. It's your program that is outputting UTF-8.

Comment: What you write in the file, that will come.You can write ANSI codes if you can't write symbols: ` handle:write('\239\240\232\226\229\242'..'\n')`

Comment: Convert your Lua file from UTF-8 to win-1251 before running it.  This way all string literals in your program would become win-1251.  (For example, you can convert with Notepad)